# How to get Text of an option present in <select> tag through Protractor

Tags: testing, protractor

```
<select class="form-control m-b slctrLevel"
[(ngModel)] = "level.id"
name = "LevelId" >
    <optgroup class="slctrLevelLabel" label = "Levels" >
        <option value = "{{levelInfo.id}}" * ngFor="let levelInfo of levelInfo" >
    {{ levelInfo.title }}
    </option>
< /optgroup>
< /select>
```

Protractor Test Code

```
 let levelPoint = 100;
 let levels = element.all(by.className("slctrLevel")).first();
 levels.getText().then(value => {
 console.log("Gamification Level :" + value);
 expect(levelPoint).toBe(value);

 });
```

[ScreenShot of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylnKX.png)

When I try to get Text from select tag . It gives whole options Text. Technically selected Value Text should be returned.
Due to which Expected Condition gets Failed.

```
 - Expected '100' to be ' 100
                          200
                          300
                          400
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong locator which will find the whole `<select>`, rather than the first option of the `<select>`.

```
let levelPoint = 100;

let levels = element.all(by.css("select.slctrLevel option"));

levels.first().getText().then(value => {
    console.log("Gamification Level :" + value);
    expect(levelPoint).toBe(value);
});
```

Comment: The Issue is when I select the option from select then after saving settings, in automation the test case will get passed when the text that is being shown in field matches with the option that I selected previously